# Roblox script: Can't get "IntValue"?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to Roblox scripting (Lua apparently) and was fiddling with a function that is called when one Part (dubbed the "Sender") is touched by another Part, which is actually a tool with a Part called "Handle" inside of it, and a third Part nested inside that. I have also added an IntValue to the latter to be read upon touching.

The object tree looks like this:

```
__Apple (Tool)
  L_Handle (Part)
    L_TouchInterest
    L_Value (IntValue)
    L_Apple (Part)
    L_Handle-to-Part Strong Joint
```

The function is called alright, and the part with the name "Handle" is correctly identified, but I cannot for the world get a hold of the IntValue using the following code:

```
function onTouch(hit)   
    print("Sender touched by "..hit.Name)
    local val = hit:FindFirstChild("IntValue", true)
    if val == not nil then
        print("Found IntValue: "..val.Name)
        if val.Name == "Cash" then
            --Get Money For Apple
            print("Players: "..game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name)
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.value = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.value + val.value 
        end
    else
        print("IntValue Not Found!")
    end 
    hit:Destroy()
end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

In other words: It keeps on logging "IntValue Not Found"! 
I have changed the name of the IntValue to "Value" and back to "IntValue" to no avail. I have been adding clones of it to several different layers of the composite object, but no results.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

BTW The object is a Tool, because the player is supposed to be able to pick it up and place it on the "Sender".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding is based around what `val == not nil` means.  The expression `not nil` evaluates to `true`, so the if-statement is really saying—

```
if val == true then
```

That only evaluates to `true` when `val` is *exactly* the Boolean value `true`.  For example, `'true' == true` is `false`.

As [your answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/140676/7804) indicates you've discovered, when you change the predicate to just—

```
if val then
```

—you will find that any values other than `false` and `nil` are "truthy" and will pass the `if`-statement.  This is [explained by the Lua manual in §3.3.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.4):

> The condition expression of a control structure can return any value. Both **false** and **nil** are considered false. All values different from **nil** and **false** are considered true (in particular, the number 0 and the empty string are also true).

---

If you find yourself using Lua a lot, I highly recommend reading through the rest of the [Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) too.  It's exceptionally clearly written.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself, although I do not fully understand why, it does stem from my inexperience with Lua. I was trying to transfer my habits from other programming languages.

This line:

```
if val == not nil then
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
if val then
```

And now it works!

Apparently what is returned by the FindFirstChild() method is a Boolean?

Comment: It works because `if val == not nil then` translates to (C-syntax) `if(val == !null)` and `!null` doesn't make sense. Or at least, that's how I read the LUA. [This question might supply some insight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664666/check-if-a-string-isnt-nil-or-empty-in-lua).